# How to know when the button is pressed and canceled Button pressing

Tags: swift, button, touchesbegan, touches, touchesended

I made a button. And used the below code. 
But it doesn't work at all.

```
override func pressesBegan(_ presses: Set<UIPress>, with event: UIPressesEvent?) {
    print("pressTest")
    btnConvert.isHidden = true
}
```

How can I know when the button is pressed and when button pressing is canceled?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the built-in UIButton functions - `.touchDown`, `.touchUpInside`, `.touchUpOutside`.

Touch begin:

```
myButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchDown)
```

Touch ends:

```
myButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpInside)
myButton.addTarget(target, action: action, for: .touchUpOutside)
```